# What can i do with this Win32 hooks problem?

Tags: c++, winapi, hook

I want to learn something about Windows Hooks. Right now, I'm only interested in "catching" messages.
So I did the following, but it doesn't work.

I want to catch the message in the same thread I'm using. I don't want to catch another thread's messages.

Can somebody explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

I install the hook as follows:

```
myhookdata.nType = WH_GETMESSAGE;
myhookdata.hkprc = GetMsgProc; 
myhookdata.hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, GetMsgProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
```

Then in the hook procedure I do this, just for testing. But the "WM_LBUTTONDOWN" never get catched!!

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GetMsgProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LPCWPSTRUCT message = (LPCWPSTRUCT)lParam;

    if (nCode < 0)
        return CallNextHookEx(myhookdata.hhook, nCode,
            wParam, lParam);

    switch (nCode)
    {
    case HC_ACTION:
        if (wParam)
            if (message->message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
                Sleep(0);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(myhookdata.hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: `lParam` point to `MSG` inside `WH_GETMESSAGE`, not to `CWPSTRUCT`.

Comment: `CWPSTRUCT` is used for `WH_CALLWNDPROC`, not `WH_GETMESSAGE`. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644981(v=vs.85)#parameters):

> lParam [in]
>
> Type: LPARAM
>
> A pointer to an MSG structure that contains details about the message.

So you only need to change the code:

```
PMSG message = (PMSG)lParam;
```

Then it works for me.

Comment: Hi, does the answer solve your issue? Please feel free to let me know if you have any issue and also accept it if it does help.